# Why SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile' going OFF sometimes

Tags: mysql

We use *(MySql 8.x)* version.  And also we set **local_infile** to ON like below.

`SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;`

But sometimes this flag goes off automatically and i see local_infile status to OFF.   I am keep enabling back again.  Why mysql is setting this to off automatically ?

I need this property in order to load local files into mysql

Ex:

```
 mysql --host=<hostname> --local-infile --database=prtspcmd --user=<user> --password=<password> --execute="TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_A;LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data/2020022704.csv' INTO TABLE TABLE_A  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, some articles suggested to update my.cnf under [mysqld], but that requires mysql restart, so i am setting "SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;" on fly.     you think updating my.cnf would resolve the issue ?